# Does clicking a href="tel:" count towards bounce/exit rate?

Tags: google-analytics

We are displaying listings in a search results format, 10 per page. For each listing we provide a tracked telephone number when displayed on mobile.

What we're trying to determine is, when a user clicks a tracked number to call the location, would this then attribute to a bounce/exit, or does Google analytics disregard this as even though the user has performed action taking them away from the page?

As essentially a phone call would be tracked as a goal, it seems counter intuitive for it also to be flagged as a bounce/exit surely?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics doesn't do anything when clicking the link. (asuming you doon't track it explicit with onclick or the like)

If a user clicks this link on his first pageview (asuming only one 1 pageview has been sent at the time) it will be a bounce if the user doesn't return and do more pageview/interactions within 30 mins.

To make sure that it's not at bounce you would need to send a pageview or an interactive event to the hit that will stop it from counting as a bounce.

Read more about bounce definition [here](https://www.optimizesmart.com/two-powerful-ways-to-reduce-bounce-rate/)